# Set background of body to transparent in fbml iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, fbml

I'm looking for a workaround that would allow me to remove the background from a `body` tag inside an fbml iframe which gets a white background by default.

I tried different methods of accessing the fbml iframe but unfortunately facebook denies any of the attempts to put something into the frame.

The bug is reported here but not much has been moving around it: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12621

Any clever/nasty way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your site is running on `facebook.com`, you can not access anything within that `iframe` (see [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

If Facebook doesn't give you an option to change it, then you can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the background in the iframe transparent by using

```
colorscheme=transparent
```

instead of `dark` or `light` :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite issue for one of the Facebook widgets I used on a project (the background was transparent and I needed a colored one). What I did was have the widget wrapped in a container div that I classed "facebook_badge", then accessed it, and the iframe via CSS like so:

```
.facebook_badge iframe {
   background: #fff;
}
```

From the sound of it, they're not real consistent with their widgets and whatnot, but it might be worth trying and playing around with (theoretically, you could access the body with `iframe body`, but I haven't tested it). You might be able to at least get it to a solid color that matches your background via the iframe itself.

Comment: FBML server tag scans your code and will throw out any unauthorized script - even a simple alert();

Comment: It's not a script. You put the CSS in your own CSS file. I've done it with the widget here: http://www.rockshortvine.com/. Like I said, they don't seem to be consistent with their widgets and what you can and can't do, so all I can tell you is what I've done with the widgets I've used.

Comment: Yeah sorry wrong reply. Anyway you have no chance to overide the css that is inside the iframe so a selector like that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook widgets as default have transparency built in?

Hence the ARIA attribute: AllowTransparency="true",

I have a like button on my site working perfectly - it doesn't validate but validation is [just a tool](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/but-it-doesnt-validate/).

You could also use the square FB like box:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://mutant-tractor.com/&amp;layout=box_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=65&amp;action=like&amp;font=segoe+ui&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=65" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;width:55px;height:60px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

FBML Like button:
http://www.shinyface.com/2010/08/16/adding-facebook-like-buttons-to-your-website/

Comment: They did have that built in by default and is even being set on the element - problem is that the body inside iframe containing facebook api gets override by an external stylesheet from facebook. And even putting style tag inside won't overide it - it's a documented facebook bug without solution for 2 months now and I'm looking for a hack/workaround for it.

Comment: Of course you could just use the FB SDK and build your own? The best solution I found is to do use the "square" like box as above; demo: http://mutant-tractor.com see left hand sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar bug in Recommendations plugin. You can vote on it here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19459

Meanwhile, you can use Activity plugin, which has a transparent background.