# Modifying gcal embed CSS with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, embed, gcal

So I've got an issue with google calendar embedding. I hate the white border and I'm trying to get rid of it but I can't modify the css inside the iframe. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with jquery? Maybe using .ready() or something? I've tried selecting the child of the iFrame with jquery but it doesn't work.

The part I need is in inline css on the body tag in the iframe, like this:

```
<iframe>
    <html>
         <body style="background-color:#FFF">
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (see [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), the same goes with the [Facebook widgets, btw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899294/set-background-of-body-to-transparent-in-fbml-iframe/4902178)).

That said, you should have some control over the colors in the tool to generate the embed code, as well as the embed code itself. Other than that, though, you can't change anything else. I share your pain, though, and wish we could customize the gcal stuff more.

Comment: raragarhr i'll just restrict the iframe width and hide overflow to cut off the border then. hopefully they don't try to scroll sideways.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers say, you can't do this due to SOP. However, your end goal can be achieved with the Google Calendar JSON API.

http://mikeclaffey.com/google-calendar-into-html/

It's going to be more complicated though. But with more responsibility comes more power.